# A conjecture on integrals of infinite products

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

The problem I would like to discuss in this post is about a conjecture on the following integrals,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos(x/n)\,dx \stackrel{?}= \pi/4 \tag{1}\\
\int_0^\infty \cos(2x) \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos(x/n)\,dx \stackrel{?}= \pi/8,\tag{2}
\end{align}
which was made, among other places, in the paper by Kent Morrison *Cosine product, Fourier transforms, and Random sums (1995)*, whose arXiv pre-print can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411380).
I have found various expression for the first integral, but have been unable to achieve anything significant. For example, by expanding 
$$\cos(x/n) = \frac{e^{ix/n}+ e^{-ix/n}}{2}$$
I have managed to reduce the infinite product to 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} 2^{-k} \sum_{\pm \,\text{permutations}} 2\cos\left( \left(1 \pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \ldots \pm \frac{1}{k}\right) x\right),$$
where the sum is over all $2^{k-1}$ permutations of the expression $$1 \pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \ldots \pm \frac{1}{k}.\tag{3}$$
After some thinking and reading of the linked paper, it seems that this product is related to the density distribution of $(3)$ in the real numbers as $k\to\infty$, but am unsure how to advance further. I had asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495575/how-to-derive-the-identity-sin-x-x-prod-n-1-infty-cosx-2n-without-usi), and the product, which this time only contains terms of the form $\cos(x/2^n), n \in \mathbb{N}$, was evaluated in the answers by using a probabilistic intepretation.
Another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151997/how-to-calculate-this-infinite-integral-of-infinite-product-of-cosine) on Math StackExchange used the product expansion
$$\cos(x) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1- \frac{4x^2}{\pi^2(2k-1)^2}\right)$$
To find that the original integral $(1)$ is just
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \prod_{\text{odd } k}\frac{\sin (x/k)}{x/k}\,dx.$$
If we consider this as a Fourier transform, 
$$f(p) =\frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ipx} \prod_{\text{odd } k}\frac{\sin (x/k)}{x/k}\,dx,$$
we are looking for $f(0)$ and $f(2)$. Converting this integral into convolutions, we see that it is
$$f(p) = \frac{1}{4} * \prod_{\text{odd } k} \pi k\chi_{[-1/k, 1/k]}(p) := \frac{1}{4} \pi\chi_{[-1, 1]} * 3\pi\chi_{[-1/3, 1/3]} * 5\pi\chi_{[-1/5, 1/5]}\ldots,$$
where $\chi_A(p)$ is the indicator function on the set $A$:
\begin{align}
\chi_A(p) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \,\,\text{if} \,\,p \in A \\
0 \,\,\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
 However, I am not sure how to evaluate this limit of repeated convolutions.

Comment: The equality of (1) with the third integral is already true for the integrands, and follows from the quoted expansion of sin(x/n)/(x/n) as infinite product, doesn't it?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteCosineProductIntegral.html

Answer (score 7):

These conjectures are both known to be false.  We have

$$
\int_0^\infty \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos(x/n)\,d x = 0.78538 \dots  
$$

while

$$ \frac{\pi}{4} = 0.78539 \dots $$

and we have

$$ \int_0^\infty \cos(2x) \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos(x/n)\,d x = $$
$$ 0.3926990816987241548078304229099378605246454 \dots$$

while

$$ \frac{\pi}{8} = $$
$$ 0.3926990816987241548078304229099378605246461\dots$$

The history of these integrals, and the reasons they have values slightly less than $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{8}$, are discussed here:

- J. M. Borwein, D. H. Bailey and R. Girgensohn, *Experimentation in Mathematics: Computational Paths to Discovery*, Wellesley, Massachusetts, A K Peters, 2004.
- J. M. Borwein, D. H. Bailey, V. Kapoor and E. W. Weisstein, [Ten problems in experimental mathematics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228956228_Ten_Problems_in_Experimental_Mathematics), *Amer. Math. Monthly* **113** (2006), 481–509.
- E. W. Weisstein, [Infinite cosine product integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteCosineProductIntegral.html), from MathWorld—A Wolfram Web Resource.
- J. C. Baez, [A curious integral](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2023/01/04/a-curious-integral/), *Azimuth*, January 4, 2023.

Comment: I highly recommend the 3b1b video on the subject of Borwein integrals: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851U557j6HE